# Sails Error: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I am trying to implement sails as middle server but I am unable to make an api call through `Sails` server. It works well when for successful api call but it won't work when Api call Failed.
it gives this error.

```
this.error(res,err);
     ^

TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at error (/Users/nitin.tiwari/owner-app-backend/api/controllers/ApiController.js:26:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/nitin.tiwari/owner-app-backend/api/services/XHR.js:54:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:381:11)
```

here is my ApiController.js

```
/**
 * ApiController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side logic for managing apis
 * @help        :: See http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Controllers
 */

var config = sails.config;

module.exports = {

  /**
   * @ApiController.ready()
   *
   * Prepare request object and calls XHR.send at the end.
   *
   */
  ready: function(req, res, method, data){
    var options;
    var data = data || '';
    var protocol = 'http';
    var success = function(response){
      return res.ok(response);
    },
    error = function(err){
      this.error(res,err);
    };
      options = {
        hostname: config.api.host,
        path: req.originalUrl,
        method: method,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }

    console.log(options,data);
    XHR.send(options, data, success, error, protocol);
  },

  /**
   * @ApiController.get()
   *
   * Serves all the get request.
   *
   * Makes XHR to Rails API and reverts the response.
   *
   */
  error:function(res,err){
    if(err.status == 422 && err.error.error.code == 41){
        var obj = {
          id: -1 
        }
        return res.ok(obj);
      }
      return res.apiError(err);
  },

  get: function(req, res){
    return this.ready(req, res, 'GET');
  }

};
```

I have implemented the error function but it is showing as it is not defined. I am unable to debug it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are using this inside `error` callBack where the reference of this is changed so `this.error` is not defined. in order to do that store the reference of this in
some variable and use that variable instead of this.

```
var protocol = 'http';
var self = this;
var success = function(response){
  return res.ok(response);
},
error = function(err){
  self.error(res,err);
};
```